# Mostrar no PHP uma consulta que é feita diretamente no phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Eu tenho uma query pronta (não fui eu que fiz) que todo mês troco os valores dos meses, copio e colo no phpMyAdmin (na aba SQL) para rodar. 
Ela me apresenta uma resposta bem bonita e estruturada em colunas.
Mas como faço para fazer a mesma resposta direto no PHP?

A query é essa:

```
SET @date_ini = '2019-02-20 00:00:00';
SET @date_end = '2019-03-19 23:59:59';
SELECT DISTINCT(`dstchannel`) as Canal,
count(1) as qtde,
SUM(IF(billsec< 30, 30, ((`billsec` DIV 6) * 6) + (IF(`billsec` % 6 > 0,6,0)))) as Segundos ,
sum(IF(billsec > 30,1,0)) as qtde_maior30,
SUM(IF(billsec > 30, ((`billsec` DIV 6) * 6) + (IF(`billsec` % 6 > 0,6,0)),0)) as Segundos_maior30
FROM astcdr.cdr WHERE `dstchannel` LIKE 'Khomp/B%' AND `calldate` BETWEEN @date_ini AND @date_end and billsec > 3 GROUP BY Canal ;
```

E a resposta que o phpMyAdmin mostra é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Cara, você vai ter que criar uma table no html, e puxar os dados que vieram do select por meio de um While, depois disso e só estruturar os dados na table que eles ficam "Bonitinhos" haha.

Vamos lá:

Para criar a conexão use isso:

```
$con = new mysqli($Conexao, $User $Senha, $Database))
```

`$Conexao = localhost (no teu caso)
$Database = Nome da tua base de dados...`

Isso Executa a Query pra ti:

```
$consulta = "SUA QUERY";
$resultado = $con->query($consulta );
```

Com esse While tu pega os dados que tua consulta Retornou:

```
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Dado: ".$row["dado"].";";
 }
```

A partir disso tu conseguia criar uma tabela dentro do php, Exemplo:

```
echo "<table>"
  echo "<tr>"
    echo "<td>".$row["dado"]."</td>"
  echo "</tr>"
echo "</table>"
```

Aí é só criar a tabela com os dados que você quer.

Comment: Eu só não sei o nome dos campos ali onde tem $row['dado']!

Comment: é o mesmo nome que ta na table